# Visual Studio Code C/C++ Extension cannot find compiler path

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Problem:
The program works but the intellisense doesnt recognize the compiler.

Specifications:
I use wsl. Installed from powershell

What i've tried:
I reinstalled both wsl,gcc and vscode and the c/c++ extension

Some Screenshots:

[Gcc location in pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uhot.png)

[The actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ui4M.png)

[what is causes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM6qa.png)

Comment: same problem. I know where you're coming from. It's not about actually compiling but about getting intellisense to work and not scream at the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, GCC installed on your virtual machine is independant of your primary OS. It seems GCC is installed on your VM. On Ubuntu/Linux, use the following commands to install a GCC compiler:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install build-essential`

Furthermore, Visual Studio is simply a text editor. If you want to compile and execute C/C++ on VS, the simplest way is to compile via Powershell on Windows provided you have GCC installed.